# Localising key combination detection to specific active parts of DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to detect keystroke combinations in one active (focused) element. However when I have focus on another element and the same keystrokes are pressed, the action shouldn't be fired.

I seem to have trouble doing this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out my jQuery plugin that would allow you to do this by selecting the element then picking the key like:

```
$('input').jkey('alt+a',function(){
  console.log('You pressed alt+a!');
})
```

Docs:
http://oscargodson.com/labs/jkey/

Source:
https://github.com/oscargodson/jkey

Comment: This does present a neat solution. Thanks. I'd like to know about how it works on different browsers. Would you happen to know?

Comment: Works in most browsers. I heard there are some issues with IE7. I haven't had time to address IE7 yet, but if you dont mind getting your hands dirty you could contribute :) IF you ever do have any other questions feel free to email me.

Comment: Will do. thanks a lot! I am primarily looking at firefox, chrome, safari and IE8+ and have already come across the key ambiguities you have documented. will let you know if I add something that might help.